# Issue with android:imeOptions

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

Why android:imeOptions doesn't work on `EditText` when i use `setOnClickListner` for `EditText`?  can any one faced this issue please help.

my **xml** code

```
    <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_current_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
                android:hint="@string/hint_current_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#b8b8b8"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:typeface="sans" >
            </EditText>

    <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_new_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_current_password"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
                android:hint="@string/hint_new_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#b8b8b8"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:typeface="sans" >
        </EditText>


        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_confirm_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_new_password"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/backwithborder"
                android:hint="@string/hint_confirm_password"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#b8b8b8"
                android:textSize="17sp"
            android:typeface="sans" >
        </EditText>
```

my **java** code

```
EditText txtOldPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_current_password);
txtOldPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                txtOldPassword.setFocusable(true);
                txtOldPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            }

        });
EditText txtNewPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_new_password);
txtNewPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                txtNewPassword.setFocusable(true);
                txtNewPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            }

        });  
EditText txtConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_confirm_password);
txtConfirmPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                txtConfirmPassword.setFocusable(true);
                txtConfirmPassword.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Please update your question with your current code

Comment: @JeroenSmit ok i will do it.

Answer (score 0):

do not use, you are casting edittext to a textview

```
TextView txtOldPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_current_password);
```

use

```
EditText txtOldPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_current_password);
```

working code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_input_username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Username Here"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_input_pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_input_username"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password Here"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: keyboard mistake i am using `EditText` :)

Comment: how many edit text are you using, imeOptions="actionNext" works when there is next edittext to go there

Comment: i'm posting my working xml code, may be it helps. first uses actionNext and second uses actonDone.

Comment: dude my issue is when i use `setonclicklistner` for edittext the `android:imeOptions` is not working if i remove `setonclicklistner` then it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your problem there? But if you want to set focus, you have to set it too:
`txtOldPassword.requestFocus();`

Comment: my issue is when i use `setonclicklistner` for `edittext` the `android:imeOptions` is not working if i remove `setonclicklistner` then it works fine